# Ubuntu SDK, how do I create a tree view in QML?

Tags: application-development, ubuntu-touch, development, ubuntu-sdk, qml

I have json data that defines comments that have children.
I am trying to display nested comments(like in hackernews or reddit) in my app.
What is the best way to go about doing it?

Answer (score 2):

The ubuntu UI Toolkit has no dedicated treeview component, neither the upstream QtQuick controls have.

But here are few interesting writing about the topic:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/632795/QML-TreeModel-and-TreeView
http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/30521